# Get name of function that called current function

Tags: kdb

I want to be able to get the function name of the function that calls the log function for logging purposes without slowing down or making the log function too complicated.

```
.log.err:{[x;y]x y}[-2;]
```

For example, if I call .log.err"log error msg" inside function f1, I want it to append the function name. So it would print "log error msg f1".

I know I could run `value .z.s` and pass that through to .log.err but I don't want to add an additional argument to the function. Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to Steve Caron for this approach which was posted to the k4 listbox on 2023.05.24:

```
f1:{a:1;.log.err"foo";a+x};
f2:{a:2;.log.err"bar";a+x};
curstack:{.Q.trp[{'err};();{3_y}]};
.log.err:{[x;y]x y," - ",last[curstack`][1;3]}[-2;];

q)f1[10]
foo - f1[10]
11
q)f2[10]
bar - f2[10]
12
```

I don't think this will work in every situation - you should study the backtrace output in more detail as you would likely need to generalise this a bit more. https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#trp-extend-trap

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Terry's solution, using some undocumented internal functions (i.e. could be subject to change in future versions of q). If we look at the code for the (documented) function [.Q.bt](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#bt-backtrace), we find `.Q.Ll` and `.Q.btx` - we can use these to get the current call stack without trapping an error.

Here's an example script that extracts the function name (as well as file & line number) of the caller:

```
.log.err:{[x;y]
 d:dbg0[2]y;
 x d[`func]," [",d[`file],":",string[d`line],"] : ",y;
 }[-2]

dbg0:{[x;y]
 f:first x _ .Q.btx .Q.Ll`;
 d:`func`file`line!3#f[1];
 d[`line]+:sum"\n"=f[2]#f[1;3];
 d
 }

f1:{.log.err"test"}
f2:{.log.err"test"}
.jm.f:{.log.err"test"}
```

Note: we pass the arg `2` to `dbg0` to remove `dbg0` and `.log.err` from the call stack, thus leaving the top frame as the caller of `.log.err`. If you were to move the code from `dbg0` into `.log.err` instead of a separate function, you'd want to change this to only drop 1 frame i.e. `.log.err`.

Demo of this in use:

```
q)f1[]
..f1 [/home/jmcmurray/test.q:15] : test
q)f2[]
..f2 [/home/jmcmurray/test.q:16] : test
q).jm.f[]
.jm.f [/home/jmcmurray/test.q:17] : test
```

Note that functions in top-level namespace are prefaced with `..` to indicate this. Of course you could change how this is formatted etc.

For a function defined interactively, rather than within a script, this is shown with no file & line number 0 i.e.

```
q)f3:{.log.err"test"}
q)f3[]
..f3 [:0] : test
```

Again as Terry mentioned you may want to look more at the backtrace output to generalise this.